# Can I query an IntegerRangeField by int?

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm currently assessing the [`IntegerRangeField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#integerrangefield) for a new model.

The docs give this [usage example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#std:fieldlookup-rangefield.contains):

```
>>> Event.objects.filter(ages__contains=NumericRange(4, 5))
<QuerySet [<Event: Soft play>]>
```

Will `Event.objects.filter(ages__contains=4)` work as well? (Can I query `IntegerRangeField` by a Python `int`?)

Comment: Here  in Django [Range fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#range-fields) shows what `__contains` maps to in Postgres operator and here [Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) shows what the operator does, so yes. Though the easiest way to determine this is try it.

Comment: Do you mean this line? `anyrange @> anyelement → boolean` Ok, I understand that Postgres in principle supports it. I'm wondering whether Django permits it as well.

Comment: Try it and see, then you will know.

Comment: FYI, the answer is yes.